# Echo command with color option in script and command works differently

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

If I run `echo -e "\e[1;31mThis is red text\e[0m"` in comand line, It prints out red text.

However, if I use write it in script file `test.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash
echo -e "\e[1;31mThis is red text\e[0m"
```

run `$ sh test.sh`

It prints out 
`-e \e[1;31mThis is red text\e[0m`

Why they act differntly?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`echo` is a shell builtin in Bash and dash (`/bin/sh`). If you run `echo` from the command line you are using the Bash builtin, if you are running your shell script with `sh` you are using the Dash builtin.

The dash version of `echo` doesn't know the `-e` option but just outputs anything verbatim without any special handling for `\` sequences.

Either use Bash to run your shell script, or use `/bin/echo` instead of `echo`:

```
/bin/echo -e "\e[1;31mThis is red text\e[0m"
```

To avoid the problems with different versions of `echo` you may want to use `printf` instead. In contrast to `echo` `printf` always interprets `\` sequences but doesn't automatically add a linefeed at the end so you have to append `\n` at the end if you want one.

As some versions of `printf` don't understand `\e` you should use `\033` instead:

```
printf "\033[1;31mThis is red text\033[0m\n"
```

Comment: It works. `/bin/echo` with dash(`/bin/sh`) and bash; `echo` with bash or `./tes.sh` both works correctly.  Code below works with `bash` only.                                                                                           if [ $UID -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "Not root user"
else
   echo "Root User"
fi

Answer (score 3):

This needs the correct command in the correct format is all.

Proper echo statement: `echo "Hello World!"`

Proper echo statement with color: `echo "\e[1;31mHello World!\e[0m"`

Adding color to a bash script is one of those very simple but easily confusing things.  =)

[This site](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) could help explain it all clearly to you. I often use it as reference because, who can remember all the correct color codes right? LOL

Answer (score 1):

Don't run it with `sh test.sh`, it prints the text in white colour like you said..After creating the script, make it executable by running,

```
sudo chmod +x /path/test.sh
```

[image]

Run the script with `sudo`,like `sudo ./test.sh` or `./test.sh` both will works.

Or

Run the script with `bash`,

```
bash /path/test.sh
```

Comment: I run `chmod a+x test.sh`, it print the text in read color. What is the difference. `./test.sh` should be equal to `sh test.sh` What happened in linux?

Comment: you don't had to use sh while running the script, you have created the script with bash interpreter `#! /bin/bash` so you have to use `bash test.sh`

Comment: And also `.` means current directory.

Comment: See the screenshot, my test.sh file is placed inside the desktop.So i moved to that desktop folder and then i run `./test.sh` ,finally it works.Please keep in mind run the script with `.` only if it was presented inside the current directory.